# Downsize screenshots while using fracional scaling

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution, screenshot, scaling, 4k-monitor

Ubuntu 20.04 | Nvidia Geforce GTX 1050 Ti

Using an 32 "4K monitor with 3840x2160 resolution works fine, but when I use fractional scaling with 150% scaling I get very big screenshots (5120x2880). Its not completely illogical but is there a way to use default size for a screenshot or do I need to edit every screenshot I take?

Comment: Kubuntu seems to be doing just fine with fractional scaling. It makes me wonder if (and I hate to say it) a KDE based desktop  might afterall be better use for me then a GNOME desktop.